# How to know what sam/cloudformation stack lambda is executing in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a sam/cloudformation template I am using to manage my stack. I use the same sam/cloudformation template across multiple stacks.

For example I have a dev stack and a prod stack. We have git and CI that updates the corresponding stack based on the branch.

My question is, how can I tell what stack/context my lambda function is running in? This would be useful for configuring DB endpoints.

I know I can setup Environment Variables through the console, but I would like to keep this in the template as much as possible. I don't see a good way to incorporate this into the template.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "my Lambda function". Obviously you can see all the resources including the Lambda function by reviewing the resources section in Cloudformation.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I suppose I meant how does my code know which lambda function it is running in? Both stacks use the same code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it is to pass in the stack name to the Lambda functions as an ENV var this way:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        STACK_NAME: !Ref AWS::StackName
```

It uses SAM's [Globals](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#globals-section) section (so the Environment is set on all Lambda's that are in the template), combined with [Cloudformation's Pseudoparameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I also found a related post after reading about environment variables. It looks like you can actually set these with the deploy cli command

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439163/aws-cloudformation-passing-environmental-variables-as-parameters-to-lambda-fun